# Firebase & React - prevent push notification when tab is closed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification

I'm implementing a push notification feature in my React app using Firebase. I'm listening to push notifications in my service worker. When it receives push notification, it sends a message to my app to show custom notification.
This works well when tab is in focus and when tab is inactive (in background). When I close all of my app tabs and then try to send push notification I don't want to show it.

Right now, I'm checking if there are any tabs alive by checking the length of `clients.matchAll` If it's zero, I return from the function. Here is simplified code that shows notification from service worker, rather than sending it to the app.

```
self.addEventListener("push", function (event) {
  if (event && event.data) {
    self.pushData = event.data.json();
    if (self.pushData) {
      clients
        .matchAll({
          type: "window",
          includeUncontrolled: true,
        })
        .then((windowClients) => {
          if (windowClients.length === 0) {
            return;
          }
          return self.registration.showNotification(
            "Show a notification."
          );
        });
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that sometimes I get notification that says `Site updated in background` Now I know that it's a safety feature and it works as intended but I was wondering is there a way to handle background messages differently and avoid that notification?

The requirements would be to only show notifications when tab is active or when at least one tab is alive in the background. It proved to be really tricky, and I'm running out of ideas.